# C# TabControl Selected event seems to not work

Tags: c#, tabcontrol

I am trying to access the event handler for selecting a tab, basically I have 3 tab pages inside of tabControl1. I want to be able to manipulate what is displaying in a listbox based on what tab is selected at the moment as a new tab is selected.
This does not work, anytime a tab page is selected it fails to show the message box, (when that line is uncommented)

```
private void tabControl1_Selected(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //MessageBox.Show(tabControl1.SelectedIndex.ToString());3

    if (tabControl1.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure of your page index in (TabPages Collection) , this command works in 2010

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is not the right assignment.  Your second parameter is wrong.

Try this:

```
private void tabControl1_Selected(object sender, TabControlEventArgs e) {
  if (e.TabPage.Name == tabPage1.Name)
    MessageBox.Show("First Tab!");
}
```

And make sure you have it wired up correctly (it sounds like you don't have the event actually handled):

```
public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();

  tabControl1.Selected += new TabControlEventHandler(tabControl1_Selected);
}
```

Comment: There we go thank you! I didn't know I had to register the event I thought it was like other buttons etc, where selected is already taken care of.

Answer (score 5):

#### Description

`Select` is not the right event. You should use `SelectedIndexChanged`.

> **SelectedIndexChanged** Occurs when the SelectedIndex property has changed.

#### Sample

```
private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (tabControl1.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - TabControl.SelectedIndexChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedindexchanged.aspx)

Comment: This does not work possibly because of similar registration problems as below I'm not sure but the next poster has gotten it to work properly. Thank you, though.

Answer (score 4):

there is an easier way to do so.
there is an event for tab selected

Enter event (in the properties of the tabPage1 itself 
not on tab control properties

```
private void tabPage1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("helllllllllllo");
}
```